# How to add an index or primary key to a user-defined table type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this user-defined type that I would like to add a primary key or index to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM sys.types st 
  JOIN sys.schemas ss 
    ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id 
  WHERE st.name = N'DistCritGroupData' 
    AND ss.name = N'dbo')
BEGIN

  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DistCritGroupData] AS TABLE
  (
    [DistCritTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemAction] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperatorType] [int] NOT NULL     
  );

END;
GO
```

I basically would like to either add a primary key or a clustered index. I tried this but I get the error 'Cannot find the object "dbo.DistCritGroupData" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DistCritGroupData] AS TABLE
  (
    [DistCritTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemAction] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperatorType] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [DistCritGroupData0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [DistCritTypeId] ASC
    )        
  );
```

I see in the Object Explorer on my user-defined table type that there are sections for "Columns", "Keys", "Constraints", and "Indexes". The questions is, how I do I add a Key or Index?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[SQL Server's `CREATE TYPE` DDL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql) supports at least two different ways of declaring the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint and other options.

- The simplest is an inline `PRIMARY KEY` modifier on a single column ([see the `<column_definition>` syntax rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql#syntax), and the `CLUSTERED`/`NONCLUSTERED` keyword is optional).

  ```sql
  CREATE TYPE dbo.DistCritGroupData AS TABLE (

      DistCritTypeId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
      ItemAction     int NOT NULL,        
      ObjectId       int NOT NULL,
      OperatorType   int NOT NULL
  );
  ```

  - Note that `UNIQUE` and `CHECK` constraints can also be declared on a single column. For example:

    ```sql
    CREATE TYPE dbo.DistCritGroupData AS TABLE (

        DistCritTypeId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        ItemAction     int NOT NULL,        
        ObjectId       int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        OperatorType   int NOT NULL CHECK ( OperatorType >= 1 AND OperatorType <= 10 )
    );
    ```
- You can also declare the `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, and `CHECK` constraints as a *table-type constraint*, located right after the column definitions:

  - You must use this approach if you have a composite `PRIMARY KEY` - or if you want to reference multiple columns in your `UNIQUE` or `CHECK` constraint.
  - Unlike in a normal `CREATE TABLE` statement these constraints are always *anonymous* and lack the `CONSTRAINT` keyword.

    - i.e. use just `PRIMARY KEY ( DistCritTypeId, ItemAction )` but *not* `CONSTRAINT PK_DistCritGroupData PRIMARY KEY ( DistCritTypeId, ItemAction )`.

    ```sql
    CREATE TYPE dbo.DistCritGroupData AS TABLE (

        DistCritTypeId int NOT NULL,
        ItemAction     int NOT NULL,        
        ObjectId       int NOT NULL,
        OperatorType   int NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY ( DistCritTypeId ),
        UNIQUE ( ObjectId ),
        CHECK ( OperatorType >= 1 AND OperatorType <= 10 )
    );
    ```
- You can also specify additional arbitrary `INDEX` objects, which are declared after the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint (if any).

  - Unlike `CREATE TABLE` DDL statements, you cannot use `CREATE INDEX` to define an index on a table-type; the `INDEX` definition *must* be part of the `CREATE TYPE` statement.
  - Also, unlike the `PRIMARY KEY`, `CHECK`, and `UNIQUE` constraints we've seen so far, `INDEX` objects on table-types *are not* anonymous.

    ```sql
    CREATE TYPE dbo.DistCritGroupData AS TABLE (

        DistCritTypeId int NOT NULL,
        ItemAction     int NOT NULL,        
        ObjectId       int NOT NULL,
        OperatorType   int NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY ( DistCritTypeId ),

        INDEX IX_ObjectId_OperatorType ( ObjectId, OperatorType )
    );
    ```
- Note there is no `FOREIGN KEY` constraint type here: table-types cannot participate in foreign-key constraints.

Answer (score 20):

[@bernd_K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451112/1501497) and [@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451124/1501497)'s answers work if it's a single column PK. For multi column, it would be:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DistCritGroupData] AS TABLE
  (
    [DistCritTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemAction] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperatorType] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ColumnA,ColumnB)
  );
```

In short, you can have PKs and UNIQUE [table constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx), but you cannot name them. This kind of makes sense, since you're going to be creating multiple objects of the same type, and the only time you're going to want to work with these constraints would be an alteration of the entire table type.

You also cannot define indexes, since those are primarily an artifact around physical storage.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth noting that you can now add certain indexes in table types in SQL 2014 with the new inline index syntax.  For example:

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DistCritGroupData] AS TABLE
  (
    [DistCritTypeId] [int] NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [ItemAction] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperatorType] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
       [ObjectId] ASC
    ),

    INDEX CIX CLUSTERED (ObjectId, OperatorType)    
  );
```

Comment: I gave you +1 for the effort, but this did not work for me on `sql server 2016`

`Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.`

Comment: Oops, I apparently left out a comma.  I just tested on SQL 2016 (SP2 CU7)

Comment: Fantastic, it is working fine now, I am also on `SQL 2016 (SP2 CU7) `

Comment: Just wondering why you have a UNIQUE constraint on the same column as the PRIMARY KEY? Surely being a primary key already enforces uniqueness? Maybe there's something I missed because of this new syntax that I'm not familiar with? Or maybe your script is just to illustrate the concept?

Comment: It's just to illustrate the various things you can now do with table types with the new syntax; you're right that my randomness led to a silly example : )

Answer (score 5):

You can specify your type like this:

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DistCritGroupData] AS TABLE
  (
    [DistCritTypeId] [int] NOT NULL primary key,
    [ItemAction] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperatorType] [int] NOT NULL
  );
```

I never learned why database people need names for primary keys. They ought be called The primary key of table xyz.

Comment: Is "The primary key of table xyz" a valid identifier? It need some name for sys.objects..

Comment: @gbn It is absolutely unique and you can evaluate the unique generated name from the system tables, if you must.

Comment: You need a named key or constraint when you're working with source control. Then named keys or constraints are very helpful.

Comment: Named PK constraints are also helpful when dropping/recreating a PK. You must reference a PK by name when you drop it and since generated names vary across environments e.g. dev and prod servers, to have a single script to drop/recreate a PK that works every time you must either 1. name the constraint or 2. select the name from sys.key_constraints and use dynamic sql to drop the constraint (which is quite messy). So you should name PKs. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190621.aspx