# dapper sql in-clause throws exception

Tags: sql, postgresql, dapper, in-clause

This may be a duplicate of [SELECT * FROM X WHERE id IN (...) with Dapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm)

I am trying to achieve :

```
connection.execute("delete from table where id in @ids", new { ids = new int[]{1,2}});
```

But it's not working. I always get : ERROR: 42883: operator does not exist: integer = integer[].

Even if I do this :

```
connection.Query<a>("select * from a where a_id in @ids", new { ids = new int[] { 12, 13 } })
```

I get the same exception.
I am accessing a postgresql database with Npgsql.
Can you tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Here's what happens at the database for the second statement :

Here's some log for the second statement :

operator does not exist: integer = integer[] at character 33

No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

select * from a where a_id in ((array[12,13])::int4[])

And this is for the first one (same as above but the last line is different)

delete from a where a_id in ((array[12,13])::int4[])

Comment: That's really odd... I can't see anything wrong with your c#. Do you perhaps have a SQL trace of what actually went to the server?

Comment: I've updated the question with some statements from the database

Comment: This is the second report of this I've seen in recent days... I have a strong suspicion that it is actually the specific ado.net provider (postgres) that is doing this, because that simply isn't the TSQL we generate... I will have to investigate

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the meanwhile, I'll put the feature on standby. Can you point me where I can find the progress of the investigation ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297173/dapper-adddynamicparams-for-in-query-with-ienumerable-parameter-in-postgres.  Probably needs to be `where id = ANY @ids`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dapper AddDynamicParams for IN query with IEnumerable parameter in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297173/dapper-adddynamicparams-for-in-query-with-ienumerable-parameter-in-postgres)

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to take look at the Postgres docs [Searching in Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html).
In brief, you should use the operator "ANY" or "ALL" or manually check the column for each value of the array.

This sql is the equivalent version of a query with the IN clause:

```
delete from table where id = any (@ids)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM lookup WHERE LOWER(discriminator) = ANY(@types)";
_connection.QueryAsync<Lookup>(query, new { types = new[] {"Prefix", "Suffix"} });
```

This works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30535329)

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me:
connection.Query("select * from a where a_id = ANY(@ids)", new { ids = new int[] { 12, 13 } })