# Collection parameters querying oracle with dapper

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

Having issue while passing the array of parameters in the WEB API service

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
   public string Getdetails([FromUri] int[] id) 
   {
    var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=h;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T"))
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        var strQuery = "SELECT PRIO_CATEGORY_ID AS PRIO, LANG_ID AS LANG, REC_DATE AS REC, REC_USER AS RECUSER, DESCR, COL_DESCR AS COL, ROW_DESCR AS DROW, ABBR FROM STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR WHERE REC_USER  IN (:p)";
        var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery, new { p = inconditions });
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
    }
}
```

Now while calling the API as `http://localhost:35432/api/Sample?id=1&id=83` it throws an error saying on `var queryResult = dbConn.Query(strQuery);`

> {"ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"}

[image]

Checked all the parenthesis and everything looks good

Comment: How about using `OracleCommand` to bind the array parameter?

Comment: @trx Show the query that runs successfully when you test it in database. Did you try to use parameters in database and get it to work? The error is a syntax error so you need to look at the query string.

Comment: This is the query that runs successfully in the DB SELECT PRIO_CATEGORY_ID AS PRIO, LANG_ID AS LANG, REC_DATE AS REC, REC_USER AS RECUSER, DESCR, COL_DESCR AS COL, ROW_DESCR AS DROW, ABBR 
FROM STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR WHERE REC_USER  IN (1,83)

Comment: Also how would we be using Parameterized query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT \* FROM X WHERE id IN (...) with Dapper ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to wrap your collection parameters in parenthesis. Dapper is not just find-and-replace, and smart enought to handle collection parameters it by itself. Try this:

```
... WHERE REC_USER IN :p
```

Check out [`List Support`](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) section.

In your `(:p)` case following kind of query generated:

```
... WHERE REC_USER IN ((1,2,3))
```

Comment: You are correct. I am wondering. Does that mean `:p` will still work? is it interchangeable with `@p` or are you restricted to `@p` alone. I get the feeling form the links you provided that it is suppose to be `@p`

Comment: @Nkosi There just an example for ms sql. You need to use syntax your database support.

Comment: Using IN is not good for larger data sets. IN is limited to exactly 1000 rows or less in most DBs I think.

Answer (score 1):

@lorond got it right with his comment and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38534423/5233410).

The links he provided confirm that your code can be refactored to

```
public class SampleController : ApiController {
   public string Getdetails([FromUri] int[] id) {
    var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=h;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T")) {
        dbConn.Open();
        var strQuery = "SELECT PRIO_CATEGORY_ID AS PRIO, LANG_ID AS LANG, REC_DATE AS REC, REC_USER AS RECUSER, DESCR, COL_DESCR AS COL, ROW_DESCR AS DROW, ABBR FROM STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR WHERE REC_USER IN @p";
        var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery, new { p = inconditions });
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked,

```
var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
var srtcon = string.Join(",",inconditions);
dbConn.Open();
var strQuery = @"SELECT PRIO_CATEGORY_ID AS PRIO, LANG_ID AS LANG, REC_DATE AS REC, REC_USER AS RECUSER, DESCR, COL_DESCR AS COL, ROW_DESCR AS DROW, ABBR FROM STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR WHERE REC_USER  IN ("+srtcon+")";
var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery);
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
```

Comment: The query should stay parameterized. It's much more secure than string concatenation, even though it's difficult to imagine the risk in this case (from the array of ints)

Answer (score -1):

Try separating your parameters with a comma. Then you can split them in your code.

http://localhost:35432/api/Sample?id=1,83

Comment: No, it doesnt return anything. Just returns an empty file. But with the same query it returns 4 records from Database.