# c# dapper error when parameter is list<int> No mapping exists from object type <>f__AnonymousType20`1[[System.Int32[]

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT SellingPrice, MarkupPercent, MarkupAmount FROM ProfitMargins WHERE QuoteId in @QuoteId";
var profitMargin = await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(sqlQuery, 
    new { QuoteId = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }
//String.Join(", ", QuoteIds.ToArray()))).ToListAsync();
```

can someone see what I am doing wrong?

> No mapping exists from object type
>   <>f__AnonymousType20`1[[System.Int32[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=]] to a known managed provider native
>   type.

I got this idea from this post: [SELECT * FROM X WHERE id IN (…) with Dapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm/) answered by: @LukeH

**UPDATE:**

I need it returned into a list .  see my whole function,  I've changed the code according to the answer posted by @JFM, but now cannot add `.ToListAsync`

@JFM

```
public static async Task<List<dynamic>> GetProfitMargin(List<int> QuoteIds)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(new MYContext().Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {   
       string sqlQuery = "SELECT SellingPrice, MarkupPercent, MarkupAmount FROM ProfitMargins WHERE QuoteId in @QuoteId";
        {
            var profitMargin =  conn.Query<dynamic>(sqlQuery
               , new { QuoteId = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }).ToListAsync());                    
        }
```

Comment: you are missing an `await` for `toListAsync`. Does it work with a regular `.ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetProfitMargin(List<int> QuoteIds)
    {

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(new MYContext().Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {   
           string sqlQuery = "SELECT SellingPrice, MarkupPercent, MarkupAmount FROM ProfitMargins WHERE QuoteId in @QuoteId";
            {
                IEnumerable<dynamic> profitMargin =  await conn.QueryAsync<dynamic>(sqlQuery
                   , new { QuoteId = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } });                    
            }
```

If you don't map it to a list or array, by default it will be an IEnuerable.

Comment: @M B and what do I return?

Comment: that works in bringing back the data, but then I have it in a hashtable (with key value), instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

Using Dapper to query and map dynamic works well for me:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT SellingPrice, MarkupPercent, MarkupAmount FROM ProfitMargins WHERE QuoteId in @QuoteId";

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnString)
{
    var profitMargin = conn.Query<dynamic>(sqlQuery
       , new { QuoteId = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } });

}
```

Comment: thanks but I still can't get it working.  I need it executed and returned as a list.  see my update above.

Comment: Why dont you just change return type Task<List<dynamic>> to Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> instead?

Comment: then I get this error:  A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature (System.Int32 SellingPrice, System.Int32 MarkupPercent, System.Int32 MarkupAmount) is required for System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=]] materialization

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what the issue is, but below is an example of how you can work with Dynamics:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestDynamicsTest()
    {
        var query = @"select 1 as 'Foo', 2 as 'Bar' union all select 3 as 'Foo', 4 as 'Bar'";

        var result = _connection.Query<dynamic>(query);

        Assert.That(result.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.True(result.Select(x => x.Foo == 1).First());
        Assert.True(result.Select(x => x.Bar == 4).Last());
    }
```

**Update**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var query = @"select 1 as 'Id', 'Foo' as 'Name' union all select 1 as 'Id', 'Bar' as 'Name'";
var result = _connection.Query<Person>(query);

foreach (var person in result)
{
    var output = string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", person.Id, person.Name);
}
```

For more examples, check out Dapper [docs](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Comment: thanks.  I don't need to handle the dynamic in the c#.  I just need to reference the field names from js, so I didn't think I have to do all that mapping you have here.  My issue is that the dynamic is returning a hashtable with key value set even when I convert it to json, normally when I have a custom list, it will convert nicely and my angular can reference easily

Comment: Then just map to an object .Query<T>

Comment: can you give me syntax>?

Comment: I see your update and I know that works great, but I was trying to avoid creating a custom class.  I wanted to do this with list<dynamic>