# How do I pass a table-valued parameter to Dapper in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, dapper, table-valued-parameters

I am using .NET Core and Dapper. My problem is that .NET Core doesn't have DataTables, and that's what Dapper uses for table-valued parameters (TVP).

I was trying to convert a `List<T>` to a `List<SqlDataRecord>`, create a SqlParameter with this list and then convert it to a DynamicParameter:

```cs
public static SqlParameter toTVP<T>(this IList<T> enumerable, string name)
{
    List<SqlDataRecord> records = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
    // filter allowed types
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => Mapper.TypeToSQLMap.ContainsKey(p.PropertyType)); 
    var definitions = properties.Select(p => Mapper.TypeToMetaData(p.Name,p.PropertyType)).ToArray();
    foreach(var item in enumerable)
    {
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null)).ToArray();
        var schema = new SqlDataRecord(definitions);
        schema.SetValues(values);
        records.Add(schema);
    }

    SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.Structured);
    result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    result.TypeName = $"{name}Type";
    result.Value = records;
    return result;
}
```

and then:

```cs
var structured = MyList.toTVP("Test");
var p = new DynamicParameters(new { });
p.Add(structured.ParameterName,structured.Value);

var result = con.Query(query, p);
```

But I got an error:

> The member of type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord` cannot be used as a parameter value.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: There's no way that could work in any case because a TVP requires the `TypeName`, and that isn't being read from `structured`. Implementing `IDynamicParameters` yourself should work, as per [this](http://www.rosengren.me/blog/extend-dapper-dynamic-parameters-to-send-table-valued-parameter-to-sql-server).

Comment: Since this question was asked the preview of .NET Core 2.0 was released and includes DataTables. 
I know it's a big deal to migrate, moreover to a preview version, but if it's a possibility for you, you can now use .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @AdrienTorris Sorry, I know your comment is a little old now but I thought I'd add that yes, DataTables are supported in .Net Core 2.0, however the  `AsTableValuedParameter()` method is not implemented, so still requires a workaround as far as I can tell

Comment: And actually this workaround is not working for me either: I get the error *System.ArgumentException: 'There are not enough fields in the Structured type.  Structured types must have at least one field.'* when the query is executed.  Oh well, it looks like it won't be too long before the original DataTable method is fully supported.

Comment: @pcdev I believe `AsTableValuedParameter()` is an extension method implemented in Dapper itself. It is possible you were missing some reference?

Answer (score 6):

As of Dapper 2.0, TVPs are natively supported. There's some sample code is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/yorek/dapper-samples/blob/master/Dapper.Samples.Advanced/SQLServerFeatures.cs

For pre-2.0 TVPs, you would need to use .NET Framework, where you can use the `.AsTableValuedParameter extension` methods, but you don't have this option in .NET Core (as of Dapper v 1.5). To solve the problem you have to create a class that implements `ICustomQueryMapper`:

```
public class TabledValuedParameter: ICustomQueryMapper
{
    public void AddParameter() {...}
}
```

And then you can use it to wrap your IEnumerable. I've written an article on the subject here:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/sql-server-specific-features-2773d894a6ae

Comment: Include the examples on your post.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a useful answer since OP is using .NET Core, not .NET Framework. If it's usable now in Dapper 2.0, just remove the .NET Framework part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Asker's solution moved to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41132350/10):

> After playing a bit with `IDynamicParameters`, I made it work.
>
> Extension method for `IEnumerable`
>
> ```
> public static DynamicWrapper toTVP<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string tableName, string typeName)
> {
>     List<SqlDataRecord> records = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
>     var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => Mapper.TypeToSQLMap.ContainsKey(p.PropertyType));
>     var definitions = properties.Select(p => Mapper.TypeToMetaData(p.Name, p.PropertyType)).ToArray();
>     foreach (var item in enumerable)
>     {
>         var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null)).ToArray();
>         var schema = new SqlDataRecord(definitions);
>         schema.SetValues(values);
>         records.Add(schema);
>     }
>
>     SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter(tableName, SqlDbType.Structured);
>     result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
>     result.TypeName = typeName;
>     result.Value = records;
>     return new DynamicWrapper(result);
> }
> ```
>
> Wrapper to implement `IDynamicParameters`
>
> ```cs
> public class DynamicWrapper : IDynamicParameters
> {
>     private readonly SqlParameter _Parameter;
>     public DynamicWrapper(SqlParameter param)
>     {
>         _Parameter = param;
>     }
>
>     public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, Identity identity)
>     {
>         command.Parameters.Add(_Parameter);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Mapper (not fully tested, only managed string to NVARCHAR because it
> throws an exception without `maxLength`)
>
> ```cs
> public class Mapper
> {
>     public static Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> TypeToSQLMap = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>()
>         {
>               {typeof (long),SqlDbType.BigInt},
>               {typeof (long?),SqlDbType.BigInt},
>               {typeof (byte[]),SqlDbType.Image},
>               {typeof (bool),SqlDbType.Bit},
>               {typeof (bool?),SqlDbType.Bit},
>               {typeof (string),SqlDbType.NVarChar},
>               {typeof (DateTime),SqlDbType.DateTime2},
>               {typeof (DateTime?),SqlDbType.DateTime2},
>               {typeof (decimal),SqlDbType.Money},
>               {typeof (decimal?),SqlDbType.Money},
>               {typeof (double),SqlDbType.Float},
>               {typeof (double?),SqlDbType.Float},
>               {typeof (int),SqlDbType.Int},
>               {typeof (int?),SqlDbType.Int},
>               {typeof (float),SqlDbType.Real},
>               {typeof (float?),SqlDbType.Real},
>               {typeof (Guid),SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier},
>               {typeof (Guid?),SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier},
>               {typeof (short),SqlDbType.SmallInt},
>               {typeof (short?),SqlDbType.SmallInt},
>               {typeof (byte),SqlDbType.TinyInt},
>               {typeof (byte?),SqlDbType.TinyInt},
>               {typeof (object),SqlDbType.Variant},
>               {typeof (DataTable),SqlDbType.Structured},
>               {typeof (DateTimeOffset),SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset}
>         };
>
>     public static SqlMetaData TypeToMetaData(string name, Type type)
>     {
>         SqlMetaData data = null;
>
>         if (type == typeof(string))
>         {
>             data = new SqlMetaData(name, SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             data = new SqlMetaData(name, TypeToSQLMap[type]);
>         }
>
>         return data;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> SQL Type for my example:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE TestType AS TABLE ( 
>   FirstName NVARCHAR(255)  
>     , GamerID INT 
>   , LastName NVARCHAR(255)
>   , Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);  
> GO
> ```
>
> Using it:
>
> ```
> List<Gamer> gamers = new List<Gamer>();
>
> gamers.Add(new Gamer {
>                 Email = new string[] { "dsadsdsa@dasddas.com" },
>                 FirstName = "Test_F0",
>                 LastName = "Test_L0",
>                 GamerID = 0,
>                 Salt = Guid.NewGuid()});
>
>             gamers.Add(new Gamer {
>                 Email = new string[] { "11111@11111.com" },
>                 FirstName = "Test_F1",
>                 LastName = "Test_L1",
>                 GamerID = 1,
>                 Salt = Guid.NewGuid()});
>
>             var structured = gamers.toTVP("GamerTable", "dbo.TestType");
>
>             using (var con = new SqlConnection(TestConnectionString))
>             {
>                 con.Open();
>
>                 string query = @"
>
>               SELECT * 
>               FROM @GamerTable t
>               WHERE t.GamerID = 1
>
>                 ";
>
> var result = con.Query(query, structured);
>
> //var result = con.Query("dbo.DapperTest", structured, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
> ```
>
> As you can see, the model stripped out the array of strings for
> emails, coz I didn't code it to have nested tvp.
> (`TypeToSQLMap.ContainsKey` part), but could be coded, changing the
> wrapper to accept an enumerable of parameters and AddParameters to
> foreach and add them. Is more about a problem with the types names,
> etc. I was thinking to create some generic types named based on the
> property types. For now, this is enough, feel free to upgrade it if i
> dont do it.