# Dapper where clause IN array, No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1 to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, dapper, bulk

I think I am following the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
but I am not sure why I am getting this error:No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1 to a known managed provider native type

This is my code:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<MyModel> QueryAllById(ICollection<string> ids)
{
    var sql = mySelectQuery + @"
                    WHERE SomeId IN @Ids                            
            ";            
    return Db.Query<MyModel>(sql, new { Ids = new[] { ids } });
}
```

Comment: You have an array of collections, try turning your collection into an array instead.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen So I changed it to " new { Ids = new[] {ids.ToArray()} } ", No I gt this error: No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear, just do `new { Ids = ids.ToArray() }`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Oh Found it!! I have an array of collection, damn. It took me an hour. I think I should get rid of the question. I made a silly mistake.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If you think the question is okay, I can give you the credit by your response, but if you think that it might distract readers from the actual point, I can vote to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert ICollection to Array.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<MyModel> QueryAllById(ICollection<string> ids)
{
    var sql = mySelectQuery + @"
                    WHERE SomeId IN @Ids                            
            ";            
    return Db.Query<MyModel>(sql, new { Ids = ids.ToArray() });
}
```

Comment: This is a exactly copy of @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Comment.

Comment: Yes, but that is completely OK! I didn't monitor the question and didn't intend to post it as an answer, so he did it instead, completely OK with me.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks mate for your kind words.  I am really sorry. I got late to post the answer. Smartis, When I saw the question, there was only one answer. after that I first created the same scenario in My project and then I post it after testing. and while posting I didn't noticed that.Apologies to All. Next time before posting an answer I'll check.