# how to send List<int> to IN operator my sql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have int list and I need to convert it so it will be possible to send it to IN operator from c# code.
I tried a lot of manipulate but got error every time.

```
string idsList = "(" + string.Join(",", ids.Select(id => $"'{id.ToString()}'")) +")";

 var sql = @"SELECT * from user
WHERE user.id IN (@idsList))";
        using (var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            var results = await connection.QueryAsync<UserQueryResponse>(sql, new
            {
                idsList= idsList,
            });
            return results.Select(raw =>raw.CreateModel());
        }
    }
```

The column type of user.id is string

Comment: What is your exception ?

Comment: "but got error every time" - What error? Of course, providing that gives a lot of context to the issue you're seeing...

Comment: What are you using to run the sql? Dapper? Ado.net?

Comment: It seems that you have complicated your code a lot. It is just _string.Join(",", ids)_

Comment: nothing, Just not getting result from the query, if I put the same value hard-coded there is a result..

Comment: Then compare the hard-coded query with the generated query, just before it runs? Without seeing your code we can only guess...

Comment: What is your query ? How is your code ? Could you share your SQL and code that calls DB?

Comment: 1 - Edit the question and add the full SQL executed against the mysql. 2- What is the column type in the mysql table?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Dapper. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388333/2057653). Try deleting the parenthesis in your query.

```
var sql = @"SELECT * from user WHERE user.id IN @idsList";
        using (var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            var results = await connection.QueryAsync<UserQueryResponse>(sql, new
            {
                idsList= idsList,
            });
            return results.Select(raw =>raw.CreateModel());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed my answer because the question was changed :)

Comment: Now it is better _assuming Dapper_ but still you have a typo in the query. Missing the open parenthesys in the IN statement

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the parameter delimiter (`@`) if your query is not parametrized.

Warning: Do note that if the `ids` list were not of type `int` you could have had a SQL Injection problem.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>{ 7, 14 ,21 };
string idsList = "(" + string.Join(",", ids.Select(id => $"'{id.ToString()}'")) +")";
/* Your idsList variable will contain "('7','14','21')" */
var sql = @"SELECT * from user WHERE user.id IN " + idsList;
```

A better approach would be using parameters:

```
StringBuilder idsList = new StringBuilder("in (");

for (int i=0; i< ids.Count; i++)
{
    // Dynamically write the IN clause
    if (i > 0) ? idsList.Append(",");
    idsList.Append("@param" + i.ToString());
    // Add the parameter that was added to the IN
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param" + i.ToString(), idsList[i])
}
idsList.Append(")");
/* idsList will cointain "in (@param0, @param1, @param2)" */
```