# How should I pass an array to the FIELD statement using Dapper, c#

Tags: c#, mysql, field, dapper

I am trying to pass an array as a parameter using Dapper. 
My array of values must go into the FIELD section.

I tried to join the array elements into a String and pass it. Still doesn't work.

```
Guid[] myArr = Ids.ToArray(); // Ids are List<Guid>
var script = @"SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id in @Ids ORDER BY FIELD(Id, @param)";
using (var connection = database.Connection)
            {
                return connection.Query<MyDataType>(script, new {Ids = Ids, param = myArr}).ToList();
            }
```

This query is just doing an Order By Id. I also passed in param = Ids. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting; short version is "that's the first time I've ever seen that syntax, and consequently Dapper currently has no support for that" - so: nothing great right now.

Comment: When I join my values to a String, I get "'1','2','3'". I wanted to get rid of the double quotes at the start and end; so I used .Trim('"'). Could not make it work

Comment: You sure those double quotes isn't just the debugger being "helpful"? It tries to format text into legal C# syntax, which means it adds quotes, and escapes problematic characters, both of which there are ample amounts of questions about here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Years later...  from my understanding dapper does not support arrays in the order by.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list into array in parameter list of dapper.

```
 var sqlQuery = "Select * from table Where Columnname IN @periodIdStr";
 var result = dapperUOW.Connection.Query<Entity>(sqlQuery ,
                        param: new { periodIdStr = periodIds.ToArray() }, transaction: dapperUOW.Transaction).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this question [SELECT * FROM X WHERE id IN (...) with Dapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm) you should be able to do a `WHERE in` with dapper but the limit of the number of items in the array is something to watch out for.

Then you could also break out the `ORDER BY FIELD` SQL and use linq to do an `OrderBy` on your results.

**Edit:**
Would this work?

```
Guid[] myArr = Ids.ToArray(); // Ids are List<Guid>
var script = @"SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id in @Ids)";
using (var connection = database.Connection)
{
    var myDataTypeObjects = connection.Query<MyDataType>(script, new {Ids = Ids}).ToList();
    myDataTypeObjects = myDataTypeObjects.OrderBy(x => Ids.IndexOf(x.Id)).ToList();
    return myDataTypeObjects;
}
```

Comment: No, I cannot use OrderBy using Linq. It defeats the whole purpose of using FIELD()