# Dynamic WHERE clause for BETWEEN with Dapper SQL Builder

Tags: dapper, sqlbuilder

I am trying to build dynamic WHERE clause with Dapper SQL builder. This works very well for all cases except BETWEEN. Have tried the below approach with BETWEEN ([just like IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm))

```
SqlBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlBuilder();
var sqlTemplate = sqlBuilder.AddTemplate(@"Select * from tbl_example /**Where**/");
sqlBuilder.Where(@"Col BETWEEN @colparam", new { paramValue });
con.Query(sqlTemplate.RawSql, sqlTemplate.Parameters);
```

When using SQL Profiler, I observed that the query generated from dapper looks like

> `Select * from tbl_example Where Col BETWEEN (@colparam1,@colparam2)`

**NOTE:**

1. *paramValue* is an array of Integer which i receive via API
2. I do understand that this can be written like *Col BETWEEN @colparam1 AND @colparam2* or replacing BETWEEN with < and >

Answer (score 0):

As you know, BETWEEN expects two parameters (@colparam1 AND @colparam2), but you're passing only a single one (@colparam).

Assuming that your array contains exactly the boundaries (min and max), try this:

```cs
sqlBuilder.Where(@"Col BETWEEN @val1 AND @val2", new { val1 = paramValue[0], val2 = paramValue[1] });
```